# Select grandchildren inside a parent div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code I am working with, as you can see, there is an id named "parent" and an id named "grandchilden". My goal is to get the content inside of this div "grandchildren". How can I achieve it?

I've tried `$(this).closest('.grandchildren')`, but didnt work.

```
<div id="parent">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      <p id="grandchildren">
        This is a content
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a ID on that div you can use `$('#grandchildren').html()`

If you don't have a ID for it, what is the pattern? `div > a > div > p` ? In that case you can use this:

```
$('div#parent > a > div > p').html();
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/96qNx/)**

Please notice the difference between [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/), if you just need to get text use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

If you have a reference like `this` you could use `find` which searches downwards, with the selected element as starting point:

```
$(this).find('.someClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent').find('#grandchildren').text();
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! I'll mark your answer correct in 11 min

Comment: But as @Sergio has written is the more exactly way because an id is a unique identifier and so access from #parent isn't necessary